# How to print the contents of a Rolling window

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

I run code like this:

```
resampleStr = '180 D'
dfRollSeries = df['Close'].rolling(resampleStr)
print(dfRollSeries)
```

The output is:

```
Rolling [window=180 D,min_periods=1,center=False,win_type=freq,axis=0,method=single]
```

I want to see the entries of the Rolling window (as a `Dataframe`?), not that it is a `rolling window`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpack the rolling object:

```
[*df['Close'].rolling('180d')]
```

If you want to print contents:

```
for s in df['Close'].rolling('180d'):
    print(s)
```